# Can't use mosh to connect remote server through frp

Tags: ssh, frp, mosh

I'm trying to use [mosh](https://mosh.org/) combined with third-party platform's frp service to connect to a remote machine (WSL) which is placed home. The mosh client is set on my Ipad's **[Blink Shell](https://blink.sh/)**. The frpc ini config is like below:

```
# mosh.ini
[common]
user = aaa
sakura_mode = true
use_recover = true
login_fail_exit = false

protocol = tcp
tcp_mux = true
pool_count = 1

# for upstream 0.50.0+
tls_enable = false
disable_custom_tls_first_byte = false

token = SakuraFrpClientToken
server_addr = frp-server-ip
server_port = 7000

[ssh]
type = tcp
local_ip = 127.0.0.1
local_port = 22
remote_port = 22818

[mosh]
type = udp
local_ip = 127.0.0.1
local_port = 60002
remote_port = 24132
```

On Blink Shell side, the **ssh** port is configed as **22818** and **mosh** port is **24132**.
The ssh connection successed but mosh didn't. The mosh client can't recive any UDP packet from `frp-server-ip:24132` and finally terminated itself.

The firewall is opened while iptables chain is listed below:

```
wsl> sudo iptables-legacy -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports 60000:61000
```

I'm sure the frp relay has been working well since I've checked frp server status and frp client output message which is like below:

```
2023/09/13 23:43:35 [I] [root.go:220] start frpc service for config file [/path/mosh.ini]
...
2023/09/13 23:43:36 [I] ...
incoming a new work connection for udp proxy, x.x.x.x:7000
```

I managed to use mosh on WSL to connect itself through `mosh -p 60002 localhost` which is ok.

I have also tried to manually start mosh-server and copy the **MOSH-KEY**, then execute `MOSH-KEY=xxx mosh-client frp-server-ip 24132` which also failed.

Is there some restrictions for using mosh through frp? I'm wondering an available blink-mosh-frp solution to remotely reach my computer at home since it's really convenient.